# Game grid not outputting in Android Studios?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

I am currently making an android app which plays the puzzle game hashi. I am currently struggling to output the game grid. i want to output a 2d array like bellow-

```
1  0  0  0  1
0  2  0  0  2
2  0  3  0  1
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  2  0  2
```

however when i run the application in the emulator it outputs just a blank white screen.

main activity-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new boardView(this));
    //sets the view to the board view to show the puzzle on open.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}
```

game board class-

```
public class boardView extends View {

    public float IslandX;
    public float IslandY;
    public int islandDiameter;

    private Canvas canvas;

    public boardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    int gameBoard[][] = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 2}};
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)

    public void DrawBoard(Canvas canvas){
        Paint Island = new Paint();
        Island.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        Island.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        float stepX = canvas.getWidth() / 5.f;
        float stepY = canvas.getHeight() / 5.f;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int R = 0; R < 5; R++) {
                IslandX = i * stepX;
                IslandY = R * stepY;
                if (gameBoard[i][R] == 0) {
                    Island.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    canvas.drawOval(IslandX, IslandY, 50, 50, Island);

                } else if (gameBoard[i][R] == 1) {
                    Island.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    canvas.drawOval(IslandX, IslandY, 50, 50, Island);

                } else if (gameBoard[i][R] == 2) {
                    Island.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    canvas.drawOval(IslandX, IslandY, 50, 50, Island);

                }


            }
        }

        }

}
```

Comment: You're not calling your DrawBoard method anywhere

Comment: Where and how would i call it?

Comment: Override `void onDraw (Canvas canvas)` in  your boardView View and move your code into there

Comment: This works, however it still only outputs the first oval at the top left hand corner and none of the other ovals?

Comment: Please stop repeating the same question. Simply edit your original post with any new information or code that you've tried, or to explain why the offered answers aren't working, and it will get bumped to the top of the active queue. There's no need to have multiples of the same question. I've closed the others as duplicates of this one, since you've got an answer and an upvote here.

Answer (score 0):

To make your board visible, you have to move your code from Drawboard to the overwritten method onDraw and in the onCreate method, you have to call invalidate() on an instance of the class boardView, that calls the onDraw method to update the screen, if visible.

Comment: what code do i write in the oncreate method? and do i copy the code inside the on create method?

Comment: something like that: `boardView bv = = (boardView) findViewById(R.id."insert ID of boardView item in XML-Layout here"); bv.invalidate();`

Comment: "and do i copy the code inside the on create method", is you mean to code from `public void DrawBoard(Canvas canvas)`, no you copy this code into `@Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)`

Comment: It is still only outputting the first integer in the array at the top left corner, but not the rest off the array?

Comment: Has the view been defined as match_parent/fill_parent both horizontal and vertical in the XML-Layout file?

Comment: I would use the Log,d() command to look for example, what values `canvas.getWidth()` and `canvas.getHeight()` send.